# Contract not returning error to React Interface

Tags: solidity, metamask, javascript, react

I have a contract which I've tested with Mocha and Remix and is working just fine. The problem is when I'm running it with my React Interface. When I call a function in my solidity contract that checks if the account exists, in mocha and remix it returns an error as expected, but in React is returning some really weird values.

Remix:
[image]

As for in React the return value of the function instead of an error (that I've placed within a Try-Catch scheme) is:
Result {0: "3963877391197344453575983046348115674221700746820753546331534351508065746944", 1: "862718293348820473429344482784628181556388621521298319395315527974912"}

The first value of the object (0) is the number of coins that account holds, and the second is a timelock (time in seconds). Thanks in advance for all the help. I'm new to this so any additional comment is highly appreciated.

The react code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Clock from './clock';
import web3 from './web3';
import tacosavings from './tacosavings';

class App extends Component {
  //Define state
  state = {
    timeLock: '',
    deposit: '',
withdraw: '',
  };

  // Define my variable assignations at the beginning
  async componentDidMount() {}

  // Define my callbacks functions
  onDeposit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    this.setState({ message: 'Waiting on transaction success...' });

    await tacosavings.methods.saveMoney(this.state.timeLock).send({
      from: accounts[0],
      value: web3.utils.toWei(this.state.deposit, 'ether'),
    });

    this.setState({ message: 'You have saved some money on Tacos!' });
  };

  onWithdraw = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

    this.setState({ message: 'Waiting on transaction success...' });

    await tacosavings.methods
      .withrawMoney(web3.utils.toWei(this.state.withdraw, 'ether'))
      .send({
        from: accounts[0],
      });

    this.setState({ message: 'You have withdrawn some money from Tacos!' });
  };

  checkAccount = async () => {
    const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
    try {
      const data = await tacosavings.methods
        .getAccount()
        .call({ from: accounts[0] });
      console.log(data);
      const { 0: money, 1: timeLeft } = data;

      this.setState({
        message: `Your account data -> 
        Tacos: ${web3.utils.fromWei(money, 'ether')} ether - 
        Timelock left: ${timeLeft} seconds`,
      });
    } catch (err) {
      this.setState({ message: 'You have no account with us!' });
    }
  };

  //Define my render method
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
          <p className="Header-Text">Welcome to Taco Bell Savings</p>
          <Clock></Clock>
        </header>

        <h2>Are you ready to save with Tacos?</h2>
        <h3> What do you want to do?</h3>

        <hr />

        <form onSubmit={this.onDeposit}>
          <h4>Save some money =)</h4>
          <div>
            <label>Amount of ether to enter: </label>
            <input
             value={this.state.deposit}
              onChange={(event) =>
                this.setState({ deposit: event.target.value })
              }
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <div>
            <label> For how long do you want to lock the money: </label>
            <input
              value={this.state.timeLock}
              onChange={(event) =>
                this.setState({ timeLock: event.target.value })
              }
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <button className="myButton">Enter</button>
        </form>

        <hr />

        <form onSubmit={this.onWithdraw}>
          <h4>Withdraw some money =(</h4>
          <div>
            <label>Amount of ether to take out: </label>
            <input
              value={this.state.withdraw}
              onChange={(event) =>
                this.setState({ withdraw: event.target.value })
              }
            />
          </div>
          <br />
          <button className="myButton">Enter</button>
        </form>

        <hr />

        <button onClick={this.checkAccount} className="myButton">
          Check Account
        </button>

        <hr />

        <h1>{this.state.message}</h1>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

My solidity code:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;


contract TacoSavings {
    //We set our storage units
    struct data {
        address client;
        uint256 savings;
        uint256 timeLock;
    }
    mapping(address => data) accountData;

    //constructor() public {}

    function saveMoney(uint256 _time) public payable {
    // This function saves the value entered by the user for a minimum amount of time
    if (accountData[msg.sender].client != address(0)) {
        //Client already has an account, update existing information
        data storage oldAccountData = accountData[msg.sender];
        oldAccountData.savings = oldAccountData.savings + msg.value;
        oldAccountData.timeLock = now + _time;

        accountData[msg.sender] = oldAccountData;
    } else {
        //Client has no account, create a new one
        data memory newAccountData;
        newAccountData.client = msg.sender;
        newAccountData.savings = msg.value;
        newAccountData.timeLock = now + _time;

        accountData[msg.sender] = newAccountData;
    }
}

function withrawMoney(uint256 _amount) public payable accountExists {
    //This function lets the user withdraw the money
    // Checks that the timeLock has expired
    require(
        now >= accountData[msg.sender].timeLock,
        "You can't withdraw your money yet."
    );
    // Checks that you are not over withdrawing
    require(
        _amount <= accountData[msg.sender].savings,
        "You can't withdraw more than you have."
    );

    address client = accountData[msg.sender].client;
    accountData[msg.sender].savings =
        accountData[msg.sender].savings -
        _amount;
    client.transfer(_amount);
}

function getAccount()
    external
    view
    accountExists
    returns (uint256, uint256)
{
    if (accountData[msg.sender].timeLock < now) {
        uint256 timeRemaining = 0;
    } else {
        timeRemaining = accountData[msg.sender].timeLock - now;
    }
    return (accountData[msg.sender].savings, timeRemaining);
}

modifier accountExists() {
    require(
        accountData[msg.sender].client != address(0),
        "Account does not exists."
    );
    _; // Take the code of the function and puts it here
}
}
```

Web3 import:

```
import Web3 from "web3";

window.ethereum.enable();

const currProvider = window.web3.currentProvider;
const web3 = new Web3(currProvider);

export default web3;
```

Local copy of contract created (interface and ABI):

```
import web3 from './web3';

const address = '0x0f6feb2b478A0955e1F91e409d6e61266aE3A9e8';
const abi = [
  {
    constant: false,
    inputs: [{ name: '_time', type: 'uint256' }],
    name: 'saveMoney',
    outputs: [],
    payable: true,
    stateMutability: 'payable',
    type: 'function',
  },
  {
    constant: false,
    inputs: [{ name: '_amount', type: 'uint256' }],
    name: 'withrawMoney',
    outputs: [],
    payable: true,
    stateMutability: 'payable',
    type: 'function',
  },
  {
    constant: true,
    inputs: [],
    name: 'getAccount',
    outputs: [
      { name: '', type: 'uint256' },
      { name: '', type: 'uint256' },
    ],
    payable: false,
    stateMutability: 'view',
    type: 'function',
  },
];

export default new web3.eth.Contract(abi, address);
```

Comment: From the error message it is failing at modifier `accountExists`. That implies `saveMoney()` has failed or it hasn't been mined yet. Check the transaction receipt for transaction's status or better generate an event when an account is modified and check the event in the receipt.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Ismael. In solidity, it is supposed to fail at the modifier because I'm trying to check my account that does not exist. 
My problem is in React, when call the getAccount function it returns a weird message (a bunch of numbers as pasted) instead of throwing an error. I used the try-catch phrase to try to catch the error but as this is returning some value is not doing so.

Comment: Probably the issue is with your BC node. Where is the web3 provided added? What chain you are interacting with?

Comment: Thanks for you message Prashant.

The web3 provider is added in a different .js file (I've updated the original post to add both that and the script where the local copy of the contract is created). Im interacting with the Rinkeby testnet.

Comment: @AlbertoV It seems to be an ongoing issue with geth and web3 https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/issues/3435

Comment: Hey Ismael, thanks for the message again. Yeah it seems like it because I'm using Infura and web3. I guess it must be something related to that then. Thanks!!